# Running Giant Gecko (EFM32GG11) bootloader-uart-xmodem software example

Tags: uart, pullup, pins, bootloader, siliconlabs

I'm new to Silicon Labs products and Simplicity Studio and was wondering if someone would walk through some basic steps to running the example serial UART bootloader on a Giant Gecko using the *bootloader-uart-xmodem* software example provided on Simplicity Studio.

I have been following the [guide](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/an0003-efm32-uart-bootloader.pdf) on the Silicon Labs site, but I'm not sure if I'm doing section 2 correctly. I need to pull the *DBG_SWCLK* pin high, but on the *EFM32GG11* datasheet, I could only find *DBG_SWCLKTCK* at pin PF0. I am having issues configuring the pin connections I need to make with my UART USB cable to the board in order to use bootloader mode. Any advice on section 2 of the guide or more resources to get started would be very helpful!

Comment: Yes, DBG_SWCLK and DBG_SWCLKTCK are the same pin

Comment: Are you using your own board or one of the standard eval/dev boards? Depending on how much you've been playing with the system, it is possible to erase the bootloader, in which case you'll need to go in with the debug connector (SWD or JTAG) and reprogram with something like Simplicity Studio or Simplicity Commander.

Comment: I'm using a standard eval board, is there any way to see if the bootloader has been erased?

Comment: So if DBG_SWCLKTCK is the debug pin, the datasheet says it is PF0, but it also says that the BOOT_TX is PF0. Why are they both the same pin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% confident in this answer, but I think there is a lot of info that will help you so I'm putting it here for the better formatting.

**What to do**

First off, if your microcontroller does not have a valid program (meaning anything with the proper checksum) in application space, the board should enter bootloader mode automatically. If you programmed the board with junk that has a proper checksum, you will need to force the device into bootloader mode.

To force into bootloader (I haven't executed this recently, but I have in the past)

- Reset the board by pulling RESETn low
- Pull DBG_SWCLKTCK high (4k pull up is recommended)
- Release RESETn and let it go high (it has an internal pull up)
- The device should now be in bootloader mode

When in bootloader mode, the device will be executing the bootloader code. The device ships from the factory with a standard bootloader that will communicate over serial using the BOOT_TX/RS pins (PF0 and PF1). The UART settings are in the doc (1 stop bit, no parity, 8 data bits

**Multi Purpose Pins**

PF0, like most microcontroller pins has a ton of capabilities. I believe that the bootloader on this device works by always booting into the bootloader, the bootloader checks the state of PF0, and if it is high, it stays in bootloader mode and configures PF0 as BOOT_TX, a boot up communication line. If PF0 is low, it checks the checksum on the application space, and if that is valid it starts execution there. Otherwise, back to bootloader mode.

The manual recommends a 4k pull up because that is strong enough to pull PF0 high, but weak enough that you won't draw too much current if PF0 drives the line low when it goes into communication mode.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I'm still sort of confused on PF0 being a multi purpose pin. Do I have to disconnect the PF0 wire from power and move to the TX pin on the USB cable after the board starts up in bootloader mode?

Comment: @DawsonNaccarato If you just have it permanently on a 4k pull up, that should be enough to gently pull it up when the bootloader checks the value, and still allow the MCU to drive it for communication. You can remove the 4k once the bootloader has started communicating.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is any default display to determine when the board is in bootloader mode? Or am I going to have to write a script to start communicating in order to determine that?

Comment: @DawsonNaccarato I believe bootloader is intended to be a minimal program, so there is nothing to say it is in bootloader mode. You may instead want to have your application to indicate that it is running

Comment: I got it working! Thank you so much!